# PredictSequence DMX query cannot be used in context

Tags: ssas, data-mining, adventureworks, dmx-ssas

I am new to SQL Server and Data Mining strategies, so I use the AdventureWorks learning dataset provided by Microsoft in order to experiment mining models and queries. I try to write a DMX Query on a Clustering Mining Model. However I keep getting the "PredictSequence function cannot be used in the context" error. I really do not understand what it means and how to deal with it. May it be that my mining model is badly defined or have I actually misunderstood how the PredictSequence works to begin with?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dmx/predictsequence-dmx?view=sql-server-ver15&fbclid=IwAR1ckzF1QZMygbOoRUO4g3YTvv1WagtXFRBslw8rTIwW8g3Tlkk2h_Z8_7c 
I have used Microsoft's documentation while trying to build this, and to me as a beginner it seems I have followed the instructions. Could someone kindly help me understand better the situation and maybe solve the issue?

If further information is needed, please kindly ask within the comments section and I will update this accordingly.

I leave an URL for the .abf file that can be used in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio in order to run my query (for me it worked using Database -> Restore, not sure if it has any other prerequisites, as far as I checked it should be enough):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-9f-HjWJF5Rq0RQ8xFZVyqQ-CI_E8PYa/view?fbclid=IwAR1vtG7U-9rWB5mm30L1vCrRFn607hBfoJp9uv7ckVODx9JkASHatgMgqXs